# Xamarin.Forms errors on a brand new project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm in VS 2017 v. 15.7.2.  I had a fully-working Xamarin.Forms project until about a week or two ago.  I believe there was a VS upgrade from 15.6 and since then, I receive inexplicable errors, even out-of-the-box upon creating a new project, before compilation or doing anything.

I cannot put the code in a block quote because the errors won't show, so here is the image:

[image: code image]

When I create a Xamarin.Forms project, I get this (scores of errors).  The detailed error reads:

> Error CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or
>   imported  XamarinTest2    C:...\XamarinTest2\XamarinTest2\XamarinTest2\App.xaml.cs   5   Active

I can see the "NETStandard.Library" package in Nuget "installed" section shows "2.0.3" yet my common Xamarin.Forms project shows "2.0.1" and the drop-down of versions shows anything else is "blocked by project".

The other 3 projects, "Android", "iOS", and "UWP" will let me choose and install "2.0.3". I tried that once and then got a message about "mixed versions". At this point, I do believe the issue I'm seeing is related to this "NETStandard" package.

Not if it would help, but I cannot figure out how to make a brand new project load/use/install "2.0.3" instead of "2.0.1".

Anyone else experiencing bizarre behavior/errors since the most recent VS update?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? This happened to me recently after installing VS 2017 on new machine.  I create a new project from the templates for Xamarin Forms, but I can't build it or run it.  Just a bunch of errors.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52174145/1462656

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by adding two packages in package source. In Visual Studio go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings. Here select the Package Sources tab in the tree on the left. You should see the following:

[image]

Name: nuget.org
Source: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Name: LiveReload
Source: `https://nugetized.blob.core.windows.net/Live-reload/index.json`