# Error building template project - Mobile App (Xamarin Forms) - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Project template for Xamarin Forms apps don't work out of the box?  Simply chose to create a new mobile app (Xamarin Forms) using Master Detail page, and .Net standard  library.  and this is the result.

BTW using a brand new installation of Visual Studio 2017 Community (v 15.8.2) on Windows 10 v 1703 OS Build 15063.0.  This should be working, I checked off all the right options in the installer.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    2   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    2   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    3   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    3   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    4   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    4   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    5   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    5   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    6   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    6   Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'XamlCompilationAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'XamlCompilation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'XamlCompilationOptions' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MasterDetailPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    11  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Dictionary<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'NavigationPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    14  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    23  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Task' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    23  Active
Error   CS1983  The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    23  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    23  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Dictionary<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'NavigationPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    13  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    16  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    16  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    18  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'MasterBehavior' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    18  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    18  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'MasterBehavior' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    18  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Enum' is not defined or imported    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'NavigationPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Detail' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0161  'MainPage.NavigateFromMenu(int)': not all code paths return a value MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    23  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    25  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Enum' is not defined or imported    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    29  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    29  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    29  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    30  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'NavigationPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    30  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    30  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Enum' is not defined or imported    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    32  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    32  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    32  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    33  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'NavigationPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    33  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    33  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    40  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    40  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    40  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Detail' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    40  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    40  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    42  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Detail' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    42  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    44  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Device' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    44  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    44  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    44  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    44  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Device' does not exist in the current context MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    44  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    45  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    45  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported   MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    45  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported  MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    47  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'IsPresented' does not exist in the current context    MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    47  Active
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported MyApp_X D:\SOURCECODE\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\MyApp_X\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs    47  Active
Error       The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\erot\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   MyApp_X.UWP         
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   MyApp_X.Android     1   Active
Warning     The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\erot\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   MyApp_X.Android         
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   MyApp_X.UWP     1   Active
Error   MSB4062 The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlGTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\erot\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. MyApp_X C:\Users\erot\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets 84  
Error   MSB4062 The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\erot\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   MyApp_X C:\Users\erot\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets 36
```

Comment: did you restore all the nuget packages?

Comment: @Jason I tried that, but it said there was nothing to restore.

Comment: Sounds indeed as nuget packages. Can you try clearing the packages folder and run the Update-Package -reinstall command from the package manager console?

Comment: update to Windows 10 1803 - Build 17134, new xamarin requires .net standard 2.0 support which was added in 1709.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks. IMO the dev environment is becoming too tightly coupled to the OS version. Shouldn't require waiting for hours to apply every single OS update before your able to develop.

Comment: this is Windows as a Service. .net standard 2.0 support was added with 1709 and xamarin forms uses it since 3.0, so you need to keep Windows 10 at last version all time

Answer (score 0):

Try installing .Net Framework 4.7.1

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2667